# How to set row batch size for incrementalCollect in Apache Spark Thrift server?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, thrift, spark-thriftserver

I enabled `spark.sql.thriftServer.incrementalCollect` in my Thrift server (Spark 3.1.2) to prevent OutOfMemory exceptions. This worked fine, but my queries are really slow now. I checked the logs and found that Thrift is querying batches of 10.000 rows.

```
INFO SparkExecuteStatementOperation: Returning result set with 10000 rows from offsets [1260000, 1270000) with 169312d3-1dea-4069-94ba-ec73ac8bef80
```

My hardware would be able to handle 10x-50x of that.
[This](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/22219) issue and [this documentation page](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html) suggest setting `spark.sql.inMemoryColumnarStorage.batchSize`, but that didn't work.

Is it possible to configure the value?

Answer (score 0):

The spark.sql.inMemoryColumnarStorage.batchSize is for caching not for the fetchSize per incrementalload.  Read the spark thrift code in open source repo to check exact usage.